# Flot: Two Time Series With Different Dates

Tags: frameworks, charts, flot

Is it possibile to have array of different dates and use Flot chart. I have to present a simple time series chart with temperature/date-time and date-time are different for time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; Flot allows multiple series, whether they're using a time axis or not.  You just need to provide the data as an array of series objects, rather than a simple array.  See the 'Introduction' section of the [API Documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I use a milliseconds for date. Is it possibile to convert and use date format?

Comment: Flot only accepts the values in milliseconds; if you wanted to provide them as text dates, you'd have to write your own code to parse them back out to timestamps before passing them to Flot.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please can you vote this question? Thank you